# Multiplying a query value with multiple select from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables A and B

```
Table A
Name  Time               Price
a     12/01/2011 12:01   1.2
a     12/01/2011 12:02   1.3     
a     12/01/2011 12:03   1.7  

Table B
Name   Date        Factor_P  Factor_Q  Factor_R
a      12/01/2011  0.234     1.456     1.445
a      12/02/2011  0.345     1.222     1.765
```

I need to do a

```
Select Price * (Factor_P * Factor_Q / Factor_R) from Table A where Name = 'a' and Time > '12/01/2011 09:30' and Time < '12/01/2011 16:00'
```

I need to fetch the three factors from Table B and do the multiplication. How do I do the multiplication with multiple values from another table after matching the date?

Comment: Which kind of data are a.Time and b.Date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT (a.Price * b.Factor_P * b.Factor_Q / b.Factor_R) AS num
FROM tableA a INNER JOIN tableB b
    ON a.Name = b.Name 
   AND TO_CHAR(a.Time, 'DD-MON-YYYY') = TO_CHAR(b.Date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
WHERE a.Name = 'a'
  AND Time BETWEEN '2011/01/12 09.30.00' AND '2011/01/12 16.00.00'
```

Comment: @aks: solution I provided should work for dates, but I cannot test it.